# How do Bathroom Marble Vanity Tops Evaporate Water Quicky?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, countertops, vanity

I bought a Marble Bathroom bathroom countertop. I'm curious why many marble countertops evaporate water quickly (as I've tested). To evaporate water, it must have good endorthermic properties. Thats why wood, metal, and other materials evaporate water better than plastic,  because surface absorbs the heat around it.

Marble typically stays more cold, regardless of surrounding temperature. Thats why it feels colder and is used for baking (to prevent melting).

**Resources:**

https://homesteady.com/13411484/why-is-marble-cold

https://www.rd.com/article/plastic-not-dry-in-dishwasher/

Do manufactuers treat bathroom countertops with something to make it evaporate water quicker? just curious, I'm doing a similar project, and wanted to treat a surface to evaporate water quicker.

I bought this earlier,

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Decorators-Collection-31-in-W-x-22-in-D-Stone-Effects-Cultured-Marble-Vanity-Top-in-Winter-Mist-with-Undermount-White-Sink-SER31-WM/206303247

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is done by evaporation?  Marble and most natural stone will also allow water to soak in.

Comment: What home improvement problem are you trying to solve. This seems more like physics theory.

Comment: You've made a couple assertions here that are false, by the way. Marble doesn't "stay more cold". That would violate the laws of physics. As the article you linked states, it just _feels_ colder.  Also, water evaporates from almost anything, regardless of its heat transfer properties. Wood is massively less endothermic than metal. It's a chuckle that you even list them together.

Comment: Worth noting that cultured marble isn’t marble.

Comment: @crip659 see article attached https://homesteady.com/13411484/why-is-marble-cold

Comment: @isherwood https://homesteady.com/13411484/why-is-marble-cold

Comment: hi @isherwood Im wondering if there is a spray or material I can apply to make surfaces evaporate water faster

Comment: Yes, I saw the article and implied as much in my comment. I'm not sure why you keep repeating yourself. You're misinterpreting what it says, apparently.

Answer (score 3):

More likely absorbing quite a bit which will then evaporate slowly. "Water going away" is not the same thing as "water evaporating."

Stone does, in fact store a lot of heat - but that's mostly not what's going on here.

You could wax your marble to reduce the rate of absorption, and if you do, water will bead up and sit there.

Comment: https://homesteady.com/13411484/why-is-marble-cold

Comment: same with plastic, https://www.rd.com/article/plastic-not-dry-in-dishwasher/

Answer (score 1):

The rate of evaporation depends on the atmospheric properties mainly.

As an example consider playing football on a hot sunny dry day compared to a hot sunny humid day.

Comment: see article here, https://homesteady.com/13411484/why-is-marble-cold

Comment: same with plastic, rd.com/article/plastic-not-dry-in-dishwasher